# Insert data in AWS ES from S3 by lambda function doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticsearch

I would like to ask you about how to correctly put the data from S3 to ES domain. I've created and configured a new ES domain, bucket and the lambda function (from this example: 
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples). All of them are created on the same location.

Everything would be fine but I tried to put something to my bucket and everything looks good - I've placed a new json file and then lambda function detected it and show the results like:

```
{
      "Records": [
            "bucket": {
                "name": "test",
                "...."
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "test.json",
                "size": 22,
                "eTag": "",
                "sequencer": ""
            }
            ....
       ]
}

2016-04-08T07:34:xxxxxxx 0 All 26 log records added to ES.
```

After all, I tried to search something in ES, but it doesn't show me any new indexes, i've checked this by url:

https://search-xxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_aliases

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers :)

Comment: can you check in the web console for your searc-xxxx cluster the indeces tab, if any ? and to review the data, you can open the kibana plugin (again the link is from the console of your cluster)

Comment: I can't configure the kibana because I must set 'index name or pattern' but like I said I don't have any indexes, except that default kibana index. I've checed the indeces tab but there i have only `kibana-4`

Comment: Are you trying to move data already stored in s3 to es?

Answer (score 0):

The index must be created before

The lambda function from the code you report https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples/blob/master/src/s3_lambda_es.js have the link of existing index

```
/* Globals */
var esDomain = {
    endpoint: 'my-search-endpoint.amazonaws.com',
    region: 'my-region',
    index: 'logs',
    doctype: 'apache'
};
```

You have updated those values and it must match the index you created

If you left `logs` you must create the logs index in elasticsearch

```
curl -XPOST 'https://search-xxxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "logs", "alias" : "logs" } }
    ]
}'
```

Just make sure the index is aligned between the creation and your lambda function

Comment: I've created index with the name from the lambda function and after that I've placed a new json file but the results is the same like before. I tried to get all results in my index by:

https://xxx.us-west-2.es.amazonaws.com/atag/_search/?size=1000&pretty=1

but it shows only like this:
http://i.imgur.com/7Gh5i5m.png

Comment: now go back to console, do you see your index in index tab, can you fire kibana

Comment: Yes, now new index exists in indices tab, however kibana after putting the index needs "Time-field name" - [image preview](http://i.imgur.com/yXVRufZ.png)

Comment: Maybe it'is a problem with a contents of the file which I try to export from S3 to ES. My lambda function try to get the data from movie.json which has only one line: { name: 'test' } ?